# How to design a summary page for the backend in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application with a number of controllers such as `users`, `sessions`, `preferences`, and `pages`.

I designed all these controllers in a RESTful way because most authors say that is the best way to do it.

But now I need to set up a Summary / Dashboard page for the user backend and I wonder how to do that in a RESTful way.

Right now I have this custom action in my `UsersController`:

```
def summary
  @title = "Summary page"  
end
```

This works but is not RESTful at all.

An alternative approach would be to set up a new `SummariesController` with a single `show` action. But that would only be 5 lines of code in a controller.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say a `DashboardsController` with a single action wouldn't be unreasonable. Not everything has to be RESTful; things like static pages and the like can't be (as they are not resources).

Comment: OK, and what action would you recommend in that case? `index` or `show`?

Comment: I would say `show`, because `index` implies you're showing a listing, or more than one.

Comment: OK, this turned out to be the right solution for me. Especially with multilingual sites controller actions map very nicely to the YAML-files. So thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just map it to the index route of the Users resource, i.e. `/users` ?

Comment: The `users#index` action displays a list of all `users` in the database, visible only to admin users. I really need that functionality so I can't replace it with something else.